# does overloading array operator need the assignment operator and the stream operators to be overloaded to use them in the main?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    int operator [] (int);
private:
    int LIST [];
};

int A::operator [] (int index)
{
    return LIST[index];
}


int main()
{
    A obj[3];
    cin >> obj [2];     // or     obj [2] = 15;
    cout << obj[1];

    return 0;
}
```

I want to know why I have to overload the assignment and stream operators to write such code in main, although I use them with a member function (which is the array operator), not with a standing alone object name.

Answer (score 1):

`int LIST [];` is not a valid array declaration. If you know the size of the array at compile time, you need to specify it explicitly, eg:`int LIST[size];` where `size` is a compile-time constant. Otherwise, use `std::vector` instead to allocate an array at runtime.

More importantly, `A obj[3];` is an array of `A` objects, which is not what you want in this situation. You need a single `A` object instead, eg: `A obj;`

When `obj` is an array, `obj[index]` will not invoke your `operator[]`. It will simply access an object at the specified index in the array, nothing more. That is why you end up having to implement the extra assignment and stream operators for `A` to make the shown code actually do things with that object:

- `cin >> obj [2];` accesses the `A` object at array index 2, and then passes that object to `operator>>`.
- `obj [2] = 15;` accesses the `A` object at array index 2, and then invokes `A::operator=` on that object.
- `cout << obj[1];` accesses the `A` object at array index 1, and then passes that object to `operator<<`.

To invoke your `operator[]` on an `A` object, you need access to a sole `A` object to begin with, not an array of `A` objects.

I *suspect* you wanted to pass `3` from `main()` into `A` to allocate the `A::LIST` member. If so, try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A(int);
    int& operator [] (int);
private:
    vector<int> LIST;
};

A::A(int count) : LIST(count) {}

int& A::operator [] (int index)
{
    return LIST[index];
}

int main()
{
    A obj(3); // calls A::A(3)
    cin >> obj[2]; // calls obj.operator[](2)
    obj[2] = 15; // calls obj.operator[](2)
    cout << obj[1]; // calls obj.operator[](1)

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/zLuNZw)

**UPDATE**: Or, if you are not allowed to use `std::vector`, then you can use `new[]`/`delete[]` instead, and follow the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) to manage the pointer properly, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A(int);
    ~A();

    // I'll leave these Rule-Of-3/5/0 items as an
    // exercise for you to implement later...
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(A&&) = delete;
    //

    int& operator [] (int);
private:
    int *LIST;
};

A::A(int count) {
    LIST = new int[count];
}

A::~A() {
    delete[] LIST;
}

int& A::operator [] (int index)
{
    return LIST[index];
}

int main()
{
    A obj(3); // calls A::A(3)
    cin >> obj[2]; // calls obj.operator[](2)
    obj[2] = 15; // calls obj.operator[](2)
    cout << obj[1]; // calls obj.operator[](1)

    return 0;
} // <-- A::~A() called here
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/gG3Jnq)

Comment: but after the correction, and creating the statement A obj; and specifying the size of the array in the class, why do i have to overload the assignment and stream operator LOGICALLY ? i mean, a statement like cin >> obj [2]; input an integer to the member function of the class (which si the array), more specifically THAT satamtent cin >> obj need the stream extraction to be overloaded

Comment: @ibrahim "*why do i have to overload the assignment and stream operator*" - In the fixed code, you won't be assigning a value to an `A`, or streaming an `A`, so you don't need those operators. That need was due to a bug in the original code. "*a statement like cin >> obj [2]; input an integer to the member function of the class (which si the array)*" - not in the original code, no. Only in the fixed code. "*THAT satamtent cin >> obj need the stream extraction to be overloaded*" - if `obj` is an `A` object, yes. The original code was streaming an `A`. The fixed code is streaming an `int`.

Comment: @ibrahim I have updated my answer. Did you even try the fixed code I presented?

Comment: of course i tried it, but i'm not supposed to use vector
i really appreciate your effort, and i got it, thank you

Comment: "*i'm not supposed to use vector*" - Then you will have to use `new[]`/`delete[]` instead. I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: thank you Remy, regarding the exercises," A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(A&&) = delete;  "  i think these are kind of overloading the assignment operator with a right hand side "delete" or something like that OR something i didn't even get close to it :D

Comment: i didn't get the exercises actually

Comment: Read up about what [`= delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions) does on a function declaration, and what the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) is. When a class manages a resource, like a dynamically allocated array, you need to handle copy and move semantics to ensure the resource is not mismanaged. My example disables the copy/move constructors and copy/move assignment operators, which your example does not need since it is not making any copies/moves of `A` objects, but you should be aware of them for the future

Comment: ok, i will read about it, and get the difference between the destructor and these functions